# Exception safe transactions on std::set

Tags: c++, exception

```
std::set<T> e;

void f(/* Some parameters. */) {
    /* Some non-throwing code. */

    try {
        e.erase(a);
        e.insert(b);
        e.erase(c);
    } catch(...) {
        // Undo failed operations.
    }
}
```

I want f to have a strong exception guarantee, regardless of type T. Let's say, erasing a and inserting b succeedes, but erasing c throws. Then I have to undo the first two operations, but that would involve inserting and erasing from e in the catch block, but these operations can also throw. Is there any way to perform this rollback? I'm using C++17.

Comment: Insert a pointer to the element instead, this cannot throw any exceptions unless you run out of memory or something (unless your element comparators are special of course).

Comment: There is always the brute force approach of copy -> modify the copy -> swap.

Comment: If your comparator can't throw, then you can `insert(b);` and only once it has succeed `erase` the other elements. `erase` can only throw if the comparator throws.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So if something throws on destruction, the strong exception guarantee is almost always pooched.

When running stack unwinding due to exceptions, if a destructor throws your program calls std terminate for pretty much the same reason.

When adding, you can just duplicate the entire collection, then add to the duplicate, then swap collections.  Then you can destroy the duplicate; but if that destruction throws, there really isn't a sane option.  You where stating this data is no longer needed, and are being informed that this operation failed.  What does that even mean?  How do you undo "this data isn't needed"?

Require lookup `<` (or `==` and `hash`) to be exception-free.  Do the same for destruction.  Then `.erase` is also nothrow.
Don't borrow trouble and posit insane types; most insane types (they can exist) can be wrapped up in a sanity-wrapper and handle exceptions elsewhen.